# Legacy Content Delivery storage on the file system - future

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5

We have a Tridion setup (2013 SP1) which we will upgrade to SDL Web 8.5 soon. In this setup pages are published to the file system. I am interested in the future of static publishing with SDL Web, since the documentation of SDL Web 8.5 calls it a '[deprecated legacy feature](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-D5DCDFED-068B-4F7E-8303-3315A8FB0487.xml&docid=GUID-D5DCDFED-068B-4F7E-8303-3315A8FB0487&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-D5DCDFED-068B-4F7E-8303-3315A8FB0487)'.

Will that mean that SDL Web 9 will no longer support it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deprecated means it will be dropped in a future release, so you are warned now that you should look into an alternative solution right now.

I don't know if it will be dropped in SDL Sites 9 yet, but it might very well be the case indeed. Best you can do is assume it won't be there anymore, and switch over to the alternative as soon as possible before you have to migrate to Sites 9.

Comment: There are still good use cases for static content deployment with Tridion. There is much less overhead and management can be easier. Is it SDL's direction that custom deployers will be needed if static deployment is desired? Or should all dreams of static be abandoned?